# response.writeHead(302) in NodeJS not redirecting in async function callback

Tags: node.js

Below is a snippet of my NodeJS server code.

```js
    async function handleLoginReq(req, res) {
        let queryDB = `
            SELECT password FROM faculty_information
            WHERE email='${userInfo["user-email"]}';
        `;
        try {
            const dbres = await client.query(queryDB);
            if (dbres.rows.length !== 0) {
                if (dbres.rows[0].password === '') {
                    const errVal = 'Please register yourself correctly';
                    res.writeHead(302, {
                        'Location': `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=${encodeURIComponent(errVal)}`
                    });
                    res.end();
                    client.end();
                } else if (userInfo["user-password"] === dbres.rows[0].password) {
                    res.writeHead(302, {
                        'Location': '/experiment_page/index.html'
                    });
                    res.end();
                    client.end();
                } else {
                    const errVal = 'Incorrect password or email address';
                    res.writeHead(302, {
                        'Location': `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=${encodeURIComponent(errVal)}`
                    });
                    res.end();
                    client.end();
                }
            } else {
                const errVal = 'Please sign up';
                console.log(errVal);
                res.statusCode(302);
                res.setHeader('Location', `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=${encodeURIComponent(errVal)}`)
                //res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=${encodeURIComponent(errVal)}` });
                res.end();
                client.end();
            }
    
        } catch (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end("Internal server error");
            client.end();
        }
    }
    
    handleLoginReq(req, res);
```

The `client.query()` function is a asynchronous function. However, none of the res.writeHead(302)'s are working inside the callback of this function. A `res.writeHead(302)` does work if I add it below the function call of `handleLoginReq(req, res);`.

```js
    handleLoginReq(req, res);
    // Below redirect works
    res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': '/experiment_page/index.html' });
    res.end();
```

The above code runs when a form is submitted on /login_page/loginPage.html.
Instead of redirecting the user to either `/experiment_page/index.html` or back to `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=something` with a URL parameter, it just reloads the page to `/login_page/loginPage.html`.

Below is the HTML for this page.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/login_page/css/loginStyles.css">
        <script src="/login_page/js/labelChange.js" defer></script>
        <script src="/login_page/js/redirectSignUp.js" defer></script>
        <script src="/login_page/js/loginValidation.js" defer></script>
        <title>DigiChit - The Online Chit System | Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><h1>DigiChit</h1></li>
                <li><a href=".navbar">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="login-info">
            <form method="POST" class="form">
                <img src="/images/avatar.png" id="avatar" alt="avatar">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="email" name="user-email" id="user-email" required>
                    <label for="user-email">Email</label>
                    <span id="email-error"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="password" name="user-password" id="user-password" required>
                    <label for="user-password">Password</label>
                    <span id="general-error"></span>
                    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" id="login-button">Login</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" id="sign-up">SignUp</button>
                    <a href="/forgot_password/forgotPass.html" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

None of the client side JS scripts are interfering with the process either. I did put `console.log()`'s in all of the other conditions, and there are no clashes either where many `res.writeHead()` are running simultaneously.

If anyone can find why this is happening?

I tried to use `res.setHeader()` and `res.statusCode()` instead of `res.writeHead()` to see if anything changed, and nothing happened. I tried using promises instead of async/await and that changed nothing either.

###################################

EDIT (Updated with async/await syntax)

###################################

Here is the server code snippet containing more info on where the function is located.

```js
    const server = https.createServer(options, async function (req, res) {
        
        // For form submissions
        if (req.method.toLowerCase() === "post") {
            let body = '';
            req.on("data", (chunk) => {
                body += chunk.toString();
            })
            
            req.on("end", async function () {
                // querystring.decode converts browser query string into an object
                const userInfo = querystring.decode(body); // userInfo is an object here
    
                // Status code 302 stands for code of redirection
                if (req.url.startsWith("/login_page/loginPage.html")) {
                    const client = createClient();
                    await client.connect();
    
                    let errVal = "";
    
                    async function handleLoginReq(req, res) {
                        // Below is the query to get user password
                        let dbQuery = `
                        SELECT password FROM faculty_information
                        WHERE email='${userInfo["user-email"]}';
                        `;
                        try {
                            const dbres = await client.query(dbQuery);
                            if (dbres.rows.length !== 0) {
                                if (dbres.rows[0].password === '') {
                                    const errVal = 'Please register yourself correctly';
                                    res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=${encodeURIComponent(errVal)}` });
                                    res.end();
                                    client.end();
                                } else if (userInfo["user-password"] === dbres.rows[0].password) {
                                    res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': '/experiment_page/index.html' });
                                    res.end();
                                    client.end();
                                } else {
                                    const errVal = 'Incorrect password or email address';
                                    res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=${encodeURIComponent(errVal)}` });
                                    res.end();
                                    client.end();
                                }
                            } else {
                                const errVal = 'Please sign up';
                                console.log(errVal);
                                res.writeHead(302, { 'Location': `/login_page/loginPage.html?error=${encodeURIComponent(errVal)}` });
                                res.end();
                                client.end();
                            } 
                            
                        } catch (err) {
                            res.writeHead(500);
                            res.end("Internal server error");
                            client.end();
                        }
                    }
    
                    await handleLoginReq(req, res);
```

Comment: I cannot see the whole route, but please try `await handleLoginReq(req, res);`

Comment: The problem is, I have this code inside `https.createServer()`'s callback which I cannot make async, hence I cannot `await handleLoginReq`

Comment: It can be async, just use `http.createServer(async function (req, res) {`

Comment: I did try that, however node gives me an error saying `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

Comment: Your `handleLoginReq` function looks fine. Please include the code where you register that function, the problem must be outside

Comment: I have edited the question to include code where the function is present.

Comment: Try this `req.on("end", async ()`. Furthermore, you must check your `client` variable. In every library I have used, `.connect` is alway async

Comment: Alright. I did do the above and sure enough, the await is working.

Yes, the `.connect` is `async`, however, even after awaiting it the redirection still is not taking place.

Let me update the code above.